# Issue to Change button value dynamically in wpf

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, button

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Button x:Name="btn_num" Width="51"  Margin="318.849,158,262.15,0" Height="45" VerticalAlignment="Top" d:LayoutOverrides="HorizontalMargin">
        <Grid Height="38.166" Width="44.833">
            <Label x:Name="lbl_2" Content="2" Margin="4.483,-2.042,7,-1.626" FontSize="11.333"/>
            <Label x:Name="lbl_1" Content="1" Margin="4.483,0,7,-19.251" FontSize="11.333" Height="41.834" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
            <Label x:Name="lbl_3" Content="3" Margin="0,8.083,-15,-11.751" FontSize="11.333" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="33.35" Foreground="Black"/>
        </Grid>
    </Button>
    <Button x:Name="btn_a" Content="A" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="225.333,158,0,0" Width="55" Foreground="Black" Height="45" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="btn_alt_Click" />
</Grid>
```

It's design will be like this

[image: Button]

```
public partial class button : Window
{
    static int _AClick = 0;
    public button()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();     
    }

    private void btn_alt_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_AClick == 0)
        {
            _AClick = 1;
            Fill();
        }
        else
        {
            btn_num.Content = "";
            _AClick = 0;
        }
    }

    public void Fill()
    {
        btn_num.Content = "3";
    }
}
```

The result after window loaded

[image: windowloaded]

If i click **A** button **first time**. The result will be like this

[image: First]

If I click **A** button **second time**. The result will be like this

[image: second]

when I click **A** button **second time**. I need the result like below. what should I do for that.

[image: actual]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of ways available in WPF to achieve this. One way to do this is to have two `ControlTemplates` (one having all three numbers and other having just one number) and then set the template of your button in code -

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">  
    <Grid.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate
            x:Key="threeNumberTemplate"
            TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Grid Height="38.166" Width="44.833"> 
                <Label x:Name="lbl_2" Content="2" Margin="4.483,-2.042,7,-1.626" FontSize="11.333"/> 
                <Label x:Name="lbl_1" Content="1" Margin="4.483,0,7,-19.251" FontSize="11.333" Height="41.834" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/> 
                <Label x:Name="lbl_3" Content="3" Margin="0,8.083,-15,-11.751" FontSize="11.333" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="33.35" Foreground="Black"/> 
            </Grid> 
        </ControlTemplate>

        <ControlTemplate
            x:Key="oneNumberTemplate"
            TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Label x:Name="lbl_3" Content="3" FontSize="11.333"/> 
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <Button x:Name="btn_num" Width="51"  Margin="318.849,158,262.15,0" Height="45" VerticalAlignment="Top" Template="{StaticResource threeNumberTemplate}"></Button>  
    <Button x:Name="btn_a" Content="A" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="225.333,158,0,0" Width="55" Foreground="Black" Height="45" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="btn_alt_Click" />  
</Grid>
```

Code behind -

```
private void btn_alt_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (_AClick == 0)
    {
        _AClick = 1;
        btn_num.Template = FindResource("oneNumberTemplate") as ControlTemplate;
    }
    else
    {
        btn_num.Template = FindResource("threeNumberTemplate") as ControlTemplate;
        _AClick = 0;
    }
}
```

Same can be achieved through triggers by making `_AClick` as `DependecyProperty` and using it's value to swap templates in triggers.

Another approach is to have two `Buttons` and hide/show them based on the `_AClick` value in code.

Comment: is there any possibilities without changing xaml code.With above code is ok for one button.But i will develop this program for lot of means ,it won't be ok.

Comment: A lot of things are possible, like changing visibility of individual label etc. It will not be possible to suggest anything without complete details of your exact requirement!

Answer (score 0):

You can create three `DataTemplate` and use `DataTemplateSelector` class to load the corresponding data template on run time.

MSDN - [DataTemplateSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector.aspx)